# Adding csv filename to a column in python (200 files)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 200 files with dates in the file name. I would like to add date from this file name into new column in each file.

I created macro in Python:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import openpyxl
import csv

os.chdir(r'\\\\\\\')

for file_name in os.listdir(r'\\\\\\'):
    with open(file_name,'r') as csvinput:
        reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

    all = []
    row = next(reader)
    row.append('FileName')
    all.append(row)

    for row in reader:
        row.append(file_name)
        all.append(row)

    with open(file_name, 'w') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerows(all)

if file_name.endswith('.csv'):
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_name)

    workbook.save(file_name)
csv_filename = pd.read_csv(r'\\\\\\')
csv_data= pd.read_csv(csv_filename, header = 0)
csv_data['filename'] = csv_filename`
```

Right now I see "InvalidFileException: File is not a zip file" and only first file has added column with the file name.

Can you please advise what am I doing wrong? BTW I,m using Python 3.4.

Many thanks,
Lukasz

Answer (score 0):

First problem, this section:

```
with open(file_name, 'w') as csvoutput:
    writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerows(all)
```

should be indented, to be included in the for loop. Now it is only executed once after the loop. This is why you only get one output file.

Second problem, the exception is probably caused by `openpyxl.load_workbook(file_name)`. Presumably openpyxl can only open actual Excel files (which are .zip files with other extension), no CSV files. Why do you want to open and save it after all? I think you can just remove those three lines.

Comment: When I tried to indent these 3 lines Python executes one file all the time :( How can I indent that to include all files in the loop? According to second problem I would like to add this file name information into every file in the folder as a additional column. When I deleted these 3 lines Python executes code for 1 first file permanently.

Comment: I updated indentation on line that you mentioned. Still not working ;(